# How to code base_url inside of a link for stylesheet using Jade/Pug?

Tags: php, pug

I've been cleaning up a project for another developer. But rather than using straight HTML inside of PHP, I'd rather do it using Jade.

This is using CodeIgniter, and the issue is the following line:

```
link(href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

The output converted from Jade to PHP gives me this and not the path:

```
<link href="&lt;?php echo base_url(); ?&gt;css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The pre-processor I am using is forcing Jade to dump to .php extension and all PHP works perfectly inside of the Jade file as long as it is on a single line using traditional PHP tags.  Tested using

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

in a regular .php file and the output shows the correct path of

```
href="localhost/src/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

But for some reason it's not working at all with the href inside of Jade/Pug file.

Thanks

Comment: for the time being since you can use traditional HTML inside of Jade, I ended up placing in

<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

and it processed it correctly.  But, I'd still like to know if it is possible doing it using straight Jade.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pug escapes attributes by default. Use [unescaped attribute](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#unescaped-attributes) syntax `(href!='value')` to get around this:

```
link(href!='<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

Comment: Sean, thank you - life saver!  It worked, I appreciate it.